# Paging in Datagridview without using dataadapter c#

Tags: c#

I want to add paging option for my datagridview. I have a datatable that fetch records from the xml file and bind it in datagridview. Xml contains so many records that are why I want to add paging option in datagridview in C #win forms.
Please help how I can achieve this task without using data adapter.
Thanks.

Comment: How are You queering the XML ? are You using Linq ?

Answer (score 0):

Page it manually.  Create another `DataTable` with same scheme and copy one page of rows to it, at the times you require.

Of course, that is one option for doing it.